# Klein wrote "the matrix-vector product can be computed by computing two dot-products.". ("Coding the Matrix" by Philip N. Klein)

Tags: matrices, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading "Coding the Matrix" by Philip N. Klein.
Klein wrote "the matrix-vector product can be computed by computing two dot-products.". (See the image below.)
But I think we need only one dot-product to compute the matrix-vector product.
Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Multiplication of a $1 \times n$ by a $n \times 1$ is the same thing as a dot product.  Doing this twice is two dot products.  There are two multiplications to perform there.

Comment: @Randall Thank you very much for your comment. $a := \mathbf{v}^T\cdot \mathbf{w}$ is a scalar. $\mathbf{u}\cdot (\mathbf{v}^T\cdot\mathbf{w}) = a\cdot\mathbf{u}$. I think there is only one dot-product $\mathbf{v}^T\cdot \mathbf{w}$.

Comment: Fair point.  Hmm...

Comment: Given that the book appears from context to be about computational complexity, it may be that Klein is counting multiplications, and the point with rank-one matrices the number of multiplications is linear in the sizes of the factors, which is asymptotically smaller than for a general matrix product. "Two dot products" might then indicate that multiplying a vector by a scalar takes as many multiplications as a dot product.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you very much for your comment.